# Create a local wireless without internet

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I would like to create a local wireless without internet.

I would like to have the possibility to connect 50 clients and access to a website using a domain name. 
That means, I need a DNS and DHCP.

I sreach on internet an I found a way to achieve that but not totally and i am not sure if it will work and if it is the best way to achieve that.

I can maybe have a mini PC (server) with ad hoc network and have the client to connect on the server but:

- Will it be possible on a connection to assign a ip to the client and set a DNS server ip on the client as the same ip of the server.

I found mini PCs but how can I know if the PC will handle a lot of client ? Which network card to choose ?

I think also that a router and configure DHCP on it to distribute the IPs but I would like to have one box ready object as a mini PC.

I need an advice on the best way to go with what i want to achieve and materials i need to buy and good references.

Comment: Why ad hoc? Why not have the PC be an access point?

Comment: i don't really know that what i found because i would like to be able to have on the same machine dhcp dns and website.

Comment: I would like to be able to have one box system to be able to transport it everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linux domain controler you will need to install [bind](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-dns-server-bind-configuration) to host your own DNS. It's a little involved to set up, but necessary if your network doesn't have a DNS server.  If you're using a windows domain controller you will need a server OS (expensive). If you only have 50 clients the DNS resources needed will be small and you could run bind from any old box, even a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). You will also need a host machine for the "website" a.k.a. an intranet. This can be the same machine as your DNS server, but can be any computer on the network. When all is done you will have your router configured with the IP of your local DNS server. The DNS server will point your local domain to whatever box hosts the intranet website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i look at Raspberry pi but i need to buy a wifi card and create ad hoc server ? I would like to have one box for all DHCP DNS and website. And be able to access to the server from client with the address name. I look for DNS and DHCP and fin bind that can be installed on debian machine. isc-dhcp-server also but my problem was the wifi card on the raspberry pi that is not provided, and don't know the criteria to choose one that can handle the whole traffic website assign ip and act as DNS all on the same machine

Comment: Well the router will handle DHCP for you. You only need a server for DNS and webhosting. Also, most wireless routers have ports for wired connections too, so you could conceivably have your pi in the same room as the router and just patch it in with a cable. The client computers can still be wireless and everything will work.

Comment: 50 clients for a DNS server is nothing, because DNS traffic is very light.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer i never work with that before and i do not know how to define the spec for the wifi traffic